# Can you change your shoes in Animal Crossing GameCube version?

Tags: animal-crossing

Can you change your shoes in Animal Crossing Game Cube version?

Comment: i'm skeptical if this is a real question considering user past questions and answers

Comment: I'm willing to give it the benefit of a doubt.  Others that have played this can weigh in with whether or not this is a valid questions.

Comment: In some of the games you can change your shoes, so I think I will let this one stand.

Answer (score 1):

In Animal Crossing (Gamecube), the only type of clothes the player could change was the ones worn on their torso. Male characters had a short-sleeved shirt shape while female characters' shirts were longer to give the appearance of a dress.

Source:  http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Crossing

Answer (score -3):

You can't change your shoes in Animal Crossing GameCube. Male players wore green socks and blue shoes while female players had blue/white striped socks and red shoes.

Comment: I've unlocked everything in Animal Crossing gamecube and there isn't any shop that sells shoes.